# How to get mixed type list from parser rule context?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I defined a parser rule which can be a list of either type A or type B:

g4: 
`sectionContent : ( WHITESPACE* ( section | ( LINE_LITERAL NEWLINE ) ) WHITESPACE*  )* ;`

generated source: cpp

```
  SectionHeaderContext* sectionHeader();

  class  SectionContentContext : public antlr4::ParserRuleContext {
  public:
    SectionContentContext(antlr4::ParserRuleContext *parent, size_t invokingState);
    virtual size_t getRuleIndex() const override;
    std::vector<SectionContext *> section();
    SectionContext* section(size_t i);
    std::vector<antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *> WHITESPACE();
    antlr4::tree::TerminalNode* WHITESPACE(size_t i);
    std::vector<antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *> LINE_LITERAL();
    antlr4::tree::TerminalNode* LINE_LITERAL(size_t i);
    std::vector<antlr4::tree::TerminalNode *> NEWLINE();
    antlr4::tree::TerminalNode* NEWLINE(size_t i);

    virtual antlrcpp::Any accept(antlr4::tree::ParseTreeVisitor *visitor) override;

  };
```

Question: From the generated source, I see that I can get a list of LINE_LITERALs, I can also get a list of SectionContext. But what if the text being parsed is a mixed list of LINE_LITERAL and SectionContext? Isn't the information being lost during th parsing? e.g.

For a input document with:

```
LINE_LITERAL_1
SectionContext_1
LINE_LITERAL_2
SectionContext_2
LINE_LITERAL_3
SectionContext_3
```

The relative ordering information between `SectionContext_1` and `LINE_LITERAL_2` is important. But using antlr, I can only retrive a list of all `LINE_LITERAL` and another list of `SectionContext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the functions you see in the derived context are convenience methods. They all work on the children list, which keeps the tokens as they have been recognized (in the order they were recognized). The `section()` method, for instance, iterates over the child list and collects all the SectionContext elements. The section method with the parameter instead iterates over the child and returns the i-th occurance of the SectionContext.

If you want to get the child contexts in the order they were recognized use the child list (`ParseTree::children` in the C++ target).

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Saw your comments in the google group discussion as well.